Fix first (two) questions with McExam package
I am writing an McExam with the McExam package with multiple versions. The first two questions are supposed to read
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mcexam}
\begin{document}
    \begin{mcquestions}

    %%%% Header questions (not be included in randomization) %%%

    \question What is the version of your question booklet?
    \begin{mcanswerslist}
        \answer[correct] Version A
        \answer Version B
    \end{mcanswerslist}

    \question Your exam will be graded only if you write your version on top of the bubble
    sheet provided. Did you write the version number on top of the bubble sheet?
    \begin{mcanswerslist}
        \answer[correct] Yes, I have written the version number on top of the bubble sheet.
        \answer No, I have not yet written the version number on top of the bubble sheet.
    \end{mcanswerslist}

    %%%% Main test questions (starting with #3, included in randomization) %%%       

    \question What is 5 + 2?
    \begin{mcanswerslist}
        \answer[correct] 7
        \answer 5
        \answer 3   
    \end{mcanswerslist}

    \question What is 1 + 3?
    \begin{mcanswerslist}
        \answer[correct] 4
        \answer 6
        \answer 2   
    \end{mcanswerslist}
    \end{mcquestions}

\end{document}

The header questions are supposed to be question #1 and question #2 in both versions of the exam.
However, I cannot figure out how to exclude these two questions in the randomization.
I have tried using the [follow] option, but the package does not allow the first question to have the follow-option.
I have also tried adapting the mcexam.sty package to exclude the first two questions from randomization or to introduce a [fixposition] option. I managed to have the first two questions always questions 1 and 2, but the randomization would also assign some other questions to be #1 and #2 and overwrite my intended question 1 and 2.
I also tried to include the two questions before starting the mcquestion environment, but I could not figure out how to tell the mcquestion environment to start the counter at 3. I tried using \setcounter, but could not figure out which counter to set.
Lastly, I tried to just have two sections of the mcquestion environment, but that would reset the counter to 1 in the second environment.
Any thoughts or suggestions?

Welcome. // Please always provide code which compiles. Your snippet can‘t. Thank you

Why do you want these two question to be part of the mcquestions environment. Wouldn't be easier to just typeset them before your actual mcquestions?

@Mane32: You are right, they do not need to be part of the mcquestion environment. However, I want the questions to be numbered #1 and #2, so that students enter the answers in the appropriate scantron line.  If they are not part of the environment, then I need to find a way to tell the mcquestion environment to start the question counter at 3. My intuition would have been to use setcounter. But I could not figure out or find any documentation on what the counter name is. Moreover, the randomization going on in the background seems to make it at least non-obvious how to start the counter at 3.

The counter is named mc@counter, however it is set to zero as part of the package code, overriding any set counter.perhaps you can edit the mcexam.sty code and change the line from \setcounter{mc@counter}{0} to 2

After playing around with the .sty file, I wound something that works.
In section 3.1 of the .sty file, questions are randomized. I replaced the lines 978 to 1007 in the original code with
\def\mc@randomizeQuestions{{    
  % Make the mcquestionblock control sequences which include macro's to set the randomization question counters 
  % exclude first two questions from randomization by setting counter to 2 and assigning the first two questions the first two numbers
  \setcounter{mc@counter}{2}
  \foreach \v in {1,...,\mc@totalNumberOfVersions}{
    \foreach \q in {1,...,2}{
      \csxdef{mc@randomQuestionNumberV\v Q\q}{\q}
      \csxdef{mc@originalQuestionNumberV\v Q\q}{\q} 
       }
    }   % For the randomization start at question q=3
  \foreach \q in {3,...,\mc@totalNumberOfQuestions}{
    \ifcsstring{mc@questionOption\q}{follow}{}{
      \refstepcounter{mc@counter}
      \csgdef{mc@questionblock\arabic{mc@counter}}{}
      }
    \csxappto{mc@questionblock\arabic{mc@counter}}{
      \noexpand\refstepcounter{mc@counter}
      \noexpand\csxdef{mc@randomQuestionNumberV\noexpand\v Q\q}{\noexpand\arabic{mc@counter}}
      \noexpand\csxdef{mc@originalQuestionNumberV\noexpand\v Q\noexpand\arabic{mc@counter}}{\q}        
      }  
    }
  % randomize question blocks
  \numdef\@numberofswaps{\mc@totalNumberOfQuestionblocks-1}
  \foreach \v in {1,...,\mc@totalNumberOfVersions}{
    \foreach \q in {1,...,\@numberofswaps}{
      \pgfmathrandominteger{\r}{\q}{\@numberofswaps}
      \numdef\r{\r+1}
      \global\letcs\@swap{mc@questionblock\r}
      \global\csletcs{mc@questionblock\r}{mc@questionblock\q}  
      \global\cslet{mc@questionblock\q}{\@swap}
      } % For the randomization  question block 2
    \setcounter{mc@counter}{2}  
    \foreach \q in {1,...,\mc@totalNumberOfQuestionblocks}{  
      \csuse{mc@questionblock\q}
      }
    }  
  }}

This worked by

assigning the first two questions to be number 1 and 2, and
increasing the mc@counter and the starting counter, respectively, in the randomization.

Since I will have the exact same two questions as header questions in every MC exam, this works for me.
However, it's not very elegant solution and I would still be interested in a better one.
